# Selecting with Xpath in Scrapy

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using Scapy to scrape some data from a site and I need help using Xpath to select "**data**" from the following.

```
<span class="result_item"><span class="text3"><span class="header_text3">**data**</span><br />
  <a href="http://website.htm">**data**</a><br />
     **data**</span> <span class="phone_button_out"><span class="phone_button" style="margin-top: 0"
    onclick="pageTracker._trackEvent('USDSearch','Call Now!F');phone_win.open('name','**data**',27101650,0)">
  Call Now!<br />
</span></span>
```

What statements can I use to select the necessary data? I hope this isn't a stupid question. If it is, please point me in the right direction.

Comment: `<span class='phone-button-out'>`  or `<span class='result_item'> `is off in the provided html. pls correct the html posted.

Comment: @parishodak This was copied and pasted. If I changed that, it wouldn't be the code I'm trying to scrape.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple data elements to get in the posted html. Assuming that `<span class="result_item">` is parent of the items, you can try the following:

To get header:

```
//span[@class='result_item']/span[@class='header_text3']/text()
```

To get anchor link data:

```
//span[@class='result_item']/a/text()
```

Also, to help with xpaths, install Firebug Addon in Firefox, then FirePath addon on Firebug. Pointing to elements will give you autogenerated xpaths (good for beginners. sometime needs xpath tuning)

Comment: I am brand new. Why is "response.xpath('//span[@class='result_item']/span[@class='header_text3']/text()')" giving me an invalid syntax error in the shell?

Comment: pls check if this works `response.selector.xpath('//span[@class='result_item']/span[@class='header_text3']/text()‌​')" ').extract()` - referred documentation of scrapy http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html

Comment: It does not, unfortunately.

Comment: @ArthurWalker maybe you get error because inside `single quotation marks ' ' ` you have to use `double quotation marks " " ` - `'//span[@class="result_item"]/span[@class="header_text3"]/text()‌​'`